# R apply function to data based on index column value

Tags: r, data.table, vectorization

Example:

```
require(data.table)
example = matrix(c(rnorm(15, 5, 1), rep(1:3, each=5)), ncol = 2, nrow = 15)
example = data.table(example)
setnames(example, old=c("V1","V2"), new=c("target", "index"))
example


threshold = 100

accumulating_cost = function(x,y) { x-cumsum(y) }
whats_left = accumulating_cost(threshold, example$target)
whats_left
```

I want `whats_left` to consist of the difference between `threshold` and the cumulative sum of values in `example$target` for which `example$index` = 1, and 2, and 3. So I used the following `for` loop:

```
rm(whats_left)

whats_left = vector("list")
for(i in 1:max(example$index)) {
  whats_left[[i]] = accumulating_cost(threshold, example$target[example$index==i])
}

whats_left = unlist(whats_left)
whats_left

plot(whats_left~c(1:15))
```

I know for loops aren't the devil in R, but I'm habituating myself to use vectorization when possible (including getting away from `apply`, being a for loop wrapper). I'm pretty sure it's possible here, but I can't figure out how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you already using `data.table` you might as well use it most basic capabilities, more specifically, the `by` argument. Try `example[, accumulating_cost(threshold, target), by = index]`

Comment: That's it! These basic capabilities are exactly what I'm struggling to learn. Thanks! Care to make this the answer?

Comment: @NigelStackhouse, check the [new HTML vignettes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Getting-started). Keep track of [this post](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/944) for the vignettes that are planned.

Comment: Very cool! Thanks @Arun, that will help me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you trying to do is accumulate the cost *by* `index`. Thus, you might want to use the `by` argument as in

```
example[, accumulating_cost(threshold, target), by = index]
```